# PHP - How to correctly print accents

Tags: php, diacritics

I'm trying to print accents, through a script, not a website, but they doesn't print correctly.
What I tried :

```
<?php 
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso8859-15');
echo "éè";
?>
```

And it gives :

```
ΘΦ
```

I'm executing this sample of code from a Command Prompt on Windows.
How can I fix it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28797100/accents-printed-differently-every-time-in-php-and-html?s=1|0.7992

Comment: strings in php are array of bytes, not arrays of characters, hence they cannot work natively with multibyte encodings, not on the commandprompt at least. your header is doing basically nothing because you are not printing on an HTML document, but just on your console, that doesn't natively supports special characters.

Answer (score 1):

change to

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso8859');
```

or

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

also you can use symbol code without space "&# 233;"

becouse your charset doesn't accept this symbols

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I tried first, but it gives me the same the result. Any idea of why ?

Answer (score 0):

This is working as you expected.

try like this.

> Just change charset=UTF-8 in header

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
echo "éè";
?>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bj7WgT)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is what I tried first, but it gives me the same the result. Any idea of why ?

Comment: i mean what you echo ing and the result also same right

Comment: Sorry, no, I still have characters not printed correctly

Comment: just click on demo link and see the answer

Comment: have you click on demo link

Comment: I have seen it, but from my side it doesn't work. I'm executing this php code from a command prompt on Windows.

Comment: just try like this put this code outside of (<?php ..?>)   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>

Comment: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></meta>
<?php 
echo "éè";
?>

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.Use following php inbuilt function to avoid those characters on given string.

```
html_entity_decode($given_string,ENT_QUOTES, "ISO-8859-1");
```